# How to solve the issue in trigger? (Does formula field update fire trigger?)

Tags: apex, trigger, master-detail

I have 4 objects

Order (parent to carset)-- >car set (parent to service) --- >Service

Simple product (lookup to service)--- > service

In "order" I have a check box "Sample_Creation_Network_Mail__c"
In car set I have a check box(formula field for order((order__c.Sample_Creation_Network_Mail__c)) "Sample_Creation_Network_Mail__c"

When I create a "car set" from related list of "order", the "service" records are created with "simple product" lookup if and only if the "order" checkbox is checked.
This scenario is working fine.

The first time in the order say "order1" the checkbox "Sample_Creation_Network_Mail__c" is unchecked. Then I try to create "car set" record say "carset1" from realted list of "order1". No service is created. It’s fine.
But when I change the existing order ("order1") record checkbox "Sample_Creation_Network_Mail__c" to be checked. Then the carset1 formula checkbox is checked when i made change in order1.
The related service is not created in car set.

how to overcome this problem ?

apex trigger:

```
Trigger Sample_CarSet_Service on Sample_Car_Set__c (after insert,after update) {

public ID recTypeSimpleProduct ;

List<Service__c> serv=new List<Service__c>();


   recTypeSimpleProduct = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType = 'Service__c'  and DeveloperName = 'Sample_Simple_Product' ].ID;
    for (Sample_Car_Set__c carSet : [Select ID,Name,Order__r.Sample_Creation_Network_Mail__c,Sample_Creation_Network_Mail__c from Sample_Car_Set__c where Id in :Trigger.newMap.keySet()]) {

        system.debug('<<<<<<<< id '+carSet .id);
        system.debug('<<<<<<<< name'+carSet .Name);

        system.debug('<<<<<<<< order'+carSet .Sample_Creation_Network_Mail__c);
        if(carSet .Sample_Creation_Network_Mail__c==true) {

            for(Simple_Product__c simplProd:[SELECT id FROM Simple_Product__c WHERE Type__c = 'Network' ]) {


                system.debug('<<<<<<<<simplProd'+simplProd);
                Service__c serviceAdds = new Service__c();
                serviceAdds .Simple_Product__c=simplProd.id;
                serviceAdds.RecordTypeId=recTypeSimpleProduct ;
                serviceAdds.Car_Set__c=carSet .id;
                serv.add(serviceAdds );
               system.debug('<<<<<<<< serv'+serv);
            }
        }
    }

   upsert serv;
    system.debug('<<<<<<<<insert serv'+serv);
}
```

Please guide me !!
Thanks in advance

Comment: is `carSet .Sample_Creation_Network_Mail__c` formula field ?

Comment: in carset i have created a formula field for order like (order__c.Sample_Creation_Network_Mail__c)

Comment: `when i made change in order1. The related service is not created in car set.`  means you r trying to update order__c fields then how come it will fire  `Sample_Car_Set__c ` trigger fire... trigger should be on order object.. fyi : if formula field update doesn't invoke trigger..

Comment: ok.so to add service records in carset based upon the checkbox value in order what i need to change in my trigger?

Comment: while creation of carset the checkbox will contain the value of "Order" checkbox.then it should not be editable (It's read only).Can we obtain this ?Give  me a idea !! @sfdcweb

Answer (score 0):

Because formula fields are automatically calculated, 
they are read-only on record detail pages and do not update record itself.

You should create an update trigger for Order object, where you will update every children.
That will fire your original trigger.

Or you can move your 'service creation' procedure to Utils class, 
and then execute it from Order trigger or Car_Set trigger.

```
public without sharing CreateServiceUtils {
    public static void createServiceBasedOnCarSet(list<Sample_Car_Set__c> carList) {
    //...
    }
}
```